# Why is Dot Net Open Auth only even generating one authorization code?

Tags: dotnetopenauth

In my implementation of ICryptoKeyStore, I am storing the data in a database.

In my database I only see one entry for the authorization code (the bucket is /dnoa/oauth_authorization_code), and one refresh token (the bucket is /dnoa/oauth_refresh_token).  Also the expiration date is July 31?  That doesn't make sense to me.  Wouldn't there be one authorization code per user per session?  I'm getting the same one all the time.

Also, does the access token (the one sent in the authorization header as the bearer token) not stored to the ICryptoKeyStore?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the authorization code is not being stored in the CryptoKeyStore database. It is only the encryption key what is stored. The access token is not stored there either.